# Facing issue when passing values in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

```
localhost/Suggest(FieldName='customunit',Value='t/min')/Tags?$top=10
```

It always treat as `localhost/Suggest(FieldName%3D%27customunit%27%2CValue%3D%27t/min%27)/Tags%3F%24top%3D10`
here see **t/min** is treated as url two url fragment but I want it to treat as single.

Can someone suggest me what I can do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the Action method code?

Comment: Is the t/min value fixed? Or dynamic? Is there any special meaning? Could  you replace 't/min' with 't\min' first, then get '\' and convert it to '/' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think before passing value to Value you need to encode
Value='t%2Fmin' which will resolve your issue